# Find exact phone number using Regular Expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find an exact phone number in a string using regular expression, but I don't want to find it by format, e.g., `012-345-67-89`, `012-3456789`, `012-345-6789`.

For that I can use for example: `[0-9]{3}(-?)[0-9]{3}(-?)[0-9]{4}`.

I need a regular expression that if a user enters: `0-12345678-9` for some reason, I can still find the exact number I'm looking for if what I'm looking for is: `0123456789`.

So basically I need an expression that finds a number regardless to the position of the `-`, if it even exists.

And I need that the number I'm looking for would stay complete and not separated, for example: `/(0123456789)/` and not: `/(012(-?)3456789)/`, so I can enter that number dynamically.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's your definition of a "phone number"?

Comment: `/^[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}$/.test(text.replace(/\D+/g, ''))`?

Comment: @Liam it can be `1234` or `2345`, like I said, it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew read again my question, I can't separate the number's digits and it needs to be and exact number so without `[0-9]`..

Comment: and what does *it needs to be dynamic*  mean? There is no magic "phone number" regex. Phone numbers vary dramatically all over the world and what if a piece of text includes numbers that don't represent a phone number? Then what?

Comment: @sdijfosdfij It's not quite clear what you are asking for. Do you need to extract a phone number from a given input? Or do you need to check, if a given phone number occurs in an input text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove all non-digits from the haystack and the needle and then check for equality

```js
const input1 = 'Here in this text is this phone number ++1-555-4838192.'
const input2 = 'Here in this text is this phone number ++1-555-1239064.'

const needle = '15551239064' // matches the phone number in input 2

const checkPhoneNumber = (input, needle) => input.replace(/\D/g, '') == needle.replace(/\D/g, '')


console.log(checkPhoneNumber(input1, needle))
console.log(checkPhoneNumber(input2, needle))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for here requires some kind of recognizable pattern for what constitutes a phone number to you.

If i read your question and your comment on other answers correctly, then something like this should do it:
`/[^\d\s]?(\d+[^\d]?)+\d+/mg`

Here is the breakdown:

1. `[^\d\s]?` means that there may be 0 or 1 non-numeric, non-whitespace first. This catches countrycodes and the like
2. `(\d+[^\d]?)+` is a repeating capture group, of which at least one match must exists. It means some amount of numeric characters may be separated by a 1 non-numeric character.
3. `\d+` is the end capture, which must end in some amount of numeric characters.
4. `mg` flags means multiple results over multiple lines. This may or may not be what you want.

Here is a simple implementation:

```js
function GetPhoneNumber(text) {
  let match = text.match(/[^\d\s]?(\d+[^\d]?)+\d+/mg);
  if (match !== null) {
    return match.map(textPart => textPart.replace(/\D/mg, ''));
  }
  return [];
}
const tests = [
  'Text here 0-123456-78-9 mor text!',
  '012-345-67-89',
  '012-3456789',
  '012-345-6789',
  'no number',
  'two numbers: +01 25 35 88888 and +02 25 35 88888',
];
tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log({
    test: test,
    numbers: GetPhoneNumber(test)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this to remove anything that is not a digit

```js
str = "0-12345678-9";
str = str.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
console.log(str);
str2 = "Text here 0-123456-78-9 mor text!";
str2 = str2.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
console.log(str2);
```

Comment: But what if the string is: `"Text here 0-123456-78-9 mor text!"` ?

Comment: It will still work. It removes anything that is not a digit. I have edited to include your new example

Comment: @Ajaypayne You could use `\D` instead of `[^\d]`. It's the same thing

Comment: @yunzen, yeah, it's just a personal style choice for me

Answer (score -1):

From what I'm able to understand, you just want to remove "-" from the input string if there are any.

If that's the case, here is your solution:

```
var _string = "12213-233-112"
var _new_string = _string.split("-").join("")
console.log(_new_string) // Output: "12213233112"
```

Comment: But what if the string is: `"Text here 0-123456-78-9 mor text!"` ?